# Setting margin to auto in a flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I was following along the tutorial on youtube [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=biOMz4puGt8&t=303s) and I got stuck in this part that's using `margin-top: auto` in a flexbox to push the last child to bottom. Can you please point out what's not working here?

```css
.navbar {
    width: 5rem;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: var(--bg-primary);
}

.navbar-nav {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-item:last-child {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">

      <ul class="navbar-nav">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="" >
            <span class="link-text">Cats</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="" >
            <span class="link-text">Cats</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="" >
            <span class="link-text">Cats</span>
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as expected, the last `<li>` is pushed **to the bottom of the parent**, but since the parent (`.navbar-nav`) has the same height, you don't see the element moving.

Increasing the `.navbar-nav` height will enable the `<li>` to move down:

```css
.navbar-nav {
    ...
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```css
.navbar {
    width: 5rem;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: var(--bg-primary);
}

.navbar-nav {
    height: 100vh;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-item:last-child {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">

      <ul class="navbar-nav">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="" >
            <span class="link-text">Cats</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="" >
            <span class="link-text">Cats</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="" >
            <span class="link-text">Cats</span>
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

you should add `height: 100%;` either

```css
.navbar {
    width: 5rem;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: var(--bg-primary);
}

.navbar-nav {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    height:100%;
}

.nav-item:last-child {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">

      <ul class="navbar-nav">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="" >
            <span class="link-text">Cats</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="" >
            <span class="link-text">Cats</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="" >
            <span class="link-text">Cats</span>
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you for your correction!

Answer (score 0):

After setting the height of `100vh` to `.navbar-nav`, you can use `flex:1` on 2nd child to make sure it takes the free space around. This will automatically push the last child to the bottom. In this case you even don't need to bother about using `margin's` to place elements inside the `flex-container` at different positions. `flexbox` properties and `flex-item` properties takes care of positioning our flex-items.

**Code Modifications:**

```
.navbar-nav{
  height:100vh;
 }
.nav-item:nth-child(2) {
    flex:1;
}
```

```css
.navbar {
    width: 5rem;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: teal;
    
}

.navbar-nav {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    height:98vh;
}

.nav-item:nth-child(2) {
    flex:1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar">

      <ul class="navbar-nav">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="" >
            <span class="link-text">Cats</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="" >
            <span class="link-text">Cats</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="" >
            <span class="link-text">Cats</span>
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>

</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** The fundamental issue with margin-top not working is already covered in the above answers. Obviously the `height` issue with flex-container `.navbar-nav` div